# Display three dots at the end of the textview

Tags: android, textview

In right side I used textview to display selected timezone, if user select it then alert dialog will open based on selection i am displaying the value.. Now the issue is I the timezone value is too length then it will not display look like the below image.. I have to replace it with "**...**" if its exceed.. If I set max length it will work for this small device.. But the text view size will change based on device width. So I am little confused how to handle this.. can you please help me to solve this issue.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight=“60dp”
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom=“10dp”
    android:visibility="visible">

  <EditText
     android:id="@+id/etZipCode"
     android:padding=“15dp”
     android:layout_marginBottom=“10dp”
     android:singleLine=true
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:maxLength=“8“
     android:inputType="text"
     android:imeOptions="actionNext" />

    <TextView
     android:padding=“15dp”
     android:layout_marginBottom=“10dp”
     android:singleLine=true
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:minHeight="50dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_dropdown_pin"
     android:layout_marginBottom=“10dp“
     android:layout_marginLeft=“5dp”/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this code is working. you must have some other issues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a `drawablePadding` attribute along with `maxLines` and `ellipsize`.

Try this,

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etZipCode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLength="8"
        android:text="3445"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_dropdown_pin"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="Alaska Standard Time"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot below,

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

The suggested solutions with

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
```

are correct, but lacks of an important detail. You are applying to your TextView a compound Drawable on the right.. to make the three dots appear in this scenario, you have to apply a `android:drawablePadding="{something}dp"` attribute to the TextView as well.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I had the same problem once, and drawablePadding did the trick ;)

Answer (score 1):

Actually (...) three dot only appear if text over sizing textView. I think you need to give three property and it will appear.

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:paddingRight="15dp"//size occupy by your arrow drawable. try with 20dp also
```

Answer (score 1):

singleLine has been depreciated

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

It's better to use the code below, it supports for various maxLines with 3 dots at end of textview

```
 android:ellipsize="end"
 android:maxLines="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by this method:

```
public static void addShowMoreDots(String targetString, TextView tvStringHolder, int charactersLimit, @Nullable final View.OnClickListener onDotsClickListener) {

    if (targetString.length() > charactersLimit) {
        String dotsString = " [ ... ]";
        targetString = targetString.substring(0, charactersLimit).concat(dotsString);
        SpannableString spannableDots = new SpannableString(targetString);


        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (onDotsClickListener != null) {
                    onDotsClickListener.onClick(view);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                ds.setUnderlineText(false);
            }
        };
        int startIndex = targetString.length() - dotsString.length() + 1; //from where [ of [...] starts
        int endIndex = targetString.length();
        spannableDots.setSpan(clickableSpan, startIndex, endIndex, 0); //
        spannableDots.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), startIndex + 1, endIndex - 1, 0);
        spannableDots.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(getAppContext(), R.color.colorButtonGreen)), startIndex + 1, endIndex - 1, 0);
        tvStringHolder.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        tvStringHolder.setText(spannableDots, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    } else {
        tvStringHolder.setText(targetString);
    }
}
```